# Change style of kendo treeview checkbox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

[image]

Here the checkboxes are draws to the top left of each node. How can I change its style so that checkboxes are little smaller in size and aligned to middle of label. Basically what is best way to change the styles of treeview and its elements. If I want to change font of labels also?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      let data = {
         "Level1":[
            {
               "id":"idlevel1",
               "name":"Level1",
               "Level2":[
                  {
                     "id":"idlevel2",
                     "name":"Level2",
                     "Level3":[
                        {
                           "id":"id1level3",
                           "name":"Level3_1",
                           "Level4":[
                              {
                                 "id":"id1level4",
                                 "name":"1_level4"
                              },
                              {
                                 "id":"id2level4",
                                 "name":"2_level4"
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "id":"id2level3",
                           "name":"Level3_2",
                           "Level4":[
                              {
                                 "id":"id1level4",
                                 "name":"1_level4"
                              },
                              {
                                 "id":"id2level4",
                                 "name":"2_level4"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      };

      $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
          data: data,

          schema:{
                  data: "Level1",
                  model:{
                        children:{
                              schema:{
                                    data:"Level2",
                                    model:{
                                          children:{
                                                schema:{
                                                      data:"Level3",
                                                      model:{
                                                            children:{
                                                                  schema:{
                                                                        data:"Level4"
                                                                  }
                                                            }
                                                      }
                                                }
                                          }
                                    }
                              }
                        }
                  }
            } 
        }),
                  checkboxes:{
            checkedChildren: true
          },
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="treeview"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrite the properties of `.k-checkbox-label:before` class definition to something like:

```
.k-checkbox-label:before {
    top: 6px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iMESUBiN/4)

Comment: @anand it just changes the element's default position.

Comment: So here we are changing position of label but I can see that check box also reduced in size

Comment: @anand So that is what you need?

Comment: How the size of check box is reduced?

Comment: @anand by the `width` and `heght` properties. The `line-height` should always match the `height` property, but it doesn't changes it's size visualy.